# Increment a named variable in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to increment a named variable in Excel, similar to the VBA command 'x = x + 1'.  I'm using the syntax:

```
=LET(Test1,Test1,Test1+1)
```

Test1 is my named variable which I elsewhere set to 1. The above formula returns 2 (as expected) but that assignment doesn't seem to persist.  Subsequent references to Test1 still return 1.

Is there a way to permanently set Test1 = Test1 + 1?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This looks to me like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: The `LET` function does not overwrite a Named Range with the value returned from that function.

Comment: Answer to your question as asked = no. Possible usable alternative: `=Test1+Sequence(3)` (which spills 2, 3, 4). But like cybernetic nomad mentioned: what is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Folks.  This isn't an XY problem.  I'm just fiddling around with Excel, trying to expand my skills.  It sounds like I can't increment or change a named value without resorting to VBA.  Thanks for the help.  :)